# Remote thread execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, distributed-computing

I have a large scale multithreaded math application written in C++ and MFC. I'm searching for a method to track thread execution (thread starts) and take it (stop it before executing and move) from a local machine and run on a remote machine regarding that all bin files and memory heap were already transfered.
It is also not possible to make severe modifications in the source code of the application.

I know that MPI is doing similar job with some modifications to the program.

Can you advice something? All ideas and links are appreciated. What I should also read?

Comment: What OS? This is usually OS specific.

Comment: @awoodland: "MFC" would tend to indicate "Windows". It has been ported to other OSes, but is rare enough on them that absent a specific statement to the contrary, Windows would be a safe guess.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - good point. I optimistically inadvertently overlooked that in the hope that it was Linux in which case I'd have an answer.

Comment: @awoodland: Have to agree that ignoring MFC is definitely the optimistic route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they use CThread to create/start their threads, you can *probably* write your own version of CThread to create/start threads remotely.

My guess is that getting things to work from there may well be non-trivial though. Windows threads (like most others) share memory space with the parent, so a thread can (for example) the parent/child can share access to common memory simply by passing a pointer. Emulating the shared memory on a remote machine will be *quite* a bit more complex than creating/running a thread there.

Comment: Thanks. I've already found a way to monitor memory changes from time to time. It is a good idea to replace standard CThread class with my own class. Do you have any idea what should I read (something that can be useful)?